# How to do when rename Domain Name in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I installed a DC on Windows Server 2012 R2 over MS Azure. Now I see that the name of the domain what I use, isn´t so good, so I must change it.

When I start Start the Active DIrectory users and computers and click with right mouse click on the domain name, I found the value change Domain.

Is it all if i change this in these field? If not, what i have to do more and what i have to do on the client computers from every user?

Thank you and best regards 
Afentiko

Comment: [You... should probably just start again from scratch, or forget the whole thing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738208%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: I agree with @HopelessN00b. Renaming an Active-Directory domain will most likely cause trouble now and in the future. If it is not absolutely mission critical, do not do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [HopelessN00b is right](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/7945/376817)